# Deduplicate Triggered Sends in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send, exclusion-script

I'm finding a difficulty with de-duplicating triggered sends in Marketing Cloud.

There are 3 Triggered Sends in the System. They can be triggered at the same time by a single transaction in Salesforce.

Triggered Sends can't be deduped out of the box so I built an exlcusion script to exclude sends which happened 1 minute ago based on the example [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/188605/using-exclusion-script-with-sent-data-view):

```
%%[ var @sendCount, @sendType

set @sendType = 'Game Win Triggered Send'

set @sendCount = DateDiff(iif(RowCount(LookupOrderedRows('DE_Name',1,'DateSent desc','EmailAddress',emailaddr, 'SendType', @sendType))==1,Field(Row(LookupOrderedRows('DE_Name',1,'DateSent desc','EmailAddress',emailaddr, 'SendType', @sendType),1),'DateSent'),'2/2/2020'),Now(),'MI')
]%% %%=v(@sendCount)=%%
```

This works perfectly for Guided Sends, but not for Triggered Sends. What happens in Triggered Sends is that records are being injected to Data Extension simultaneously and share the same JobID, ListID and even BatchID!

Now I'm wondering how to handle this requirement in SFMC. Thanks for any hint or advise.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs has suggested a possible way with granular exclusion here which I'm about to test: https://gist.github.com/wvpv/b83961f289942ff327cf8baacc0c741b and https://gist.github.com/wvpv/4c63402feb5004d7614f6f1c57620332

Comment: I would be interested in why there are multiple requests being triggered, please elaborate on why the deduplication can't happen at that level.

Comment: @Mac Finally followed this approach and fixed the issue on the level when duplicate triggered sends are initiated in a third system.