# How can I limit customers to only get one email a week?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder

I have many marketing campaigns running at once, and there is a risk that subscribers may fall into multiple campaigns, therefore receiving multiple comms in one week. Is there any way to limit how many communications a customer receives in one week from within a journey?

I've tried writing a query using a  _send data view, which works fine, but I wouldn't be able to use that within a live journey.

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen this? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/188605/using-exclusion-script-with-sent-data-view