# Exclusion script working in one Busines unit but not in others

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, exclusion-script

I have beed using this approach for exclusion script as outlined here by mr Eliot: [Using Exclusion Script with _Sent Data View](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/188605/using-exclusion-script-with-sent-data-view)

Basically I keep logic in a block and cal it in the exclusion script box with treatascontent:

```
%%[
set @test = RowCount(LookupRows('_Sent','SubscriberKey',_subscriberKey))
]%% 
%%=v(@test)=%%
```

…

```
TreatAsContent(ContentBlockbyID('68452'))
```

We hav beein using it for many months in main BU but when I set up in a different BU and test inside email it errors. What would be the reason? I did change the block ID to refkect the ID of block from new BU.

Comment: Probably the code you call inside ContentBlockByID is not ready to be run in a different BU. Without seeing that, we cannot help much. In those two rows, obviously only the number of the block could be at fault. Also relevant information could be if either one of your BUs, "main BU" or the other one is Parent BU.